# range can't iterate over list [x y]

Tags: list, for-loop, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

I have this template in my helm chart:

```
{{ $appEnvs := list "dev" "uat" }}

{{- range $env := $appEnvs }}
...
{{- end }}
```

I am getting this error :

```
<$appEnvs>: range can't iterate over [dev uat]
```

I spent longtime trying many things like :
`{{- range $env := toYaml $appEnvs }}` and `{{- range $env := tuple $appEnvs }}` and others.. but no way.

However, when i put the list directly without variable , it works.. I mean `{{- range $env := list "dev" "uat" }}` works !?!?

How to iterate over a VARIABLE created by the sprig function `list` ?

Comment: Is the template exactly like what you show?  That seems like it should work.  The `[value1 value2]` syntax is the default Go serialization for lists, and I could imagine seeing that if you were doing something like trying to return a list from a template (you can't, templates only return strings).

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  test: |-
    {{- $appEnvs := list "dev" "uat" }}
    {{- range $idx, $env := $appEnvs }}
    {{ $env }}: {{ $env }}
    {{- end }}
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  test: |-
    dev: dev
    uat: uat
```

2. [range](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#looping-with-the-range-action)

```yaml
...
    {{- $appEnvs := list "dev" "uat" }}
    {{- range $appEnvs }}
    {{ . }}: {{ . }}
    {{- end }}
...
```

output

```yaml
...
    dev: dev
    uat: uat
...
```